# responseJSON object undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I send data from Python Flask in JSON format. I'm able to grab the data, and use a for loop in the inspector on my locally hosted page, `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. However, when I apply the same JavaScript to a local JS file, and connect it to my HTML page, I keep getting undefined for the JSON data from the responseJSON. I'm trying to get the array from the JSON data, specifically the `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]`. Then I can use it in a for loop to generate a list.

`app3/static/js/index.js`:

```
console.log("connected to index.js!!!");
var getData = $.get("/send");
console.log(getData.responseJSON.result);
```

`app3/views.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/send")
def send():
    return jsonify({"result": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`app3/templates/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Index</h3>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static',filename='js/index.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error in the Chrome console is at line 5 on the js file. Specifically, `console.log(getData.responseJSON.result);`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
    at index.js:5
```

It worked initially, but now I consistently get this error. It works perfectly fine in the inspector. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking a look at the jquery docs for [.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), it seems like getData is undefined because it doesn't return anything. The example they have is:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Try logging inside that success callback. You can also set a breakpoint on line 5 (with your log) in devtools and inspect getData before everything blows up.

**Example of using promise**

```
$.get("/send").then(function (data){ 
    // Executes after response is received
    // data is the response returned
    console.log(data) 
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it. Had to modify it from "ajax/test.html" to "/send". Unfortunately it doesn't make any difference as I need to get the arrays. So, for example, var getData = $.get("/send"); Then, getData.responseJSON.result which should give an array of integer values.

Comment: Try $.get("/send").then((data) => { console.log(data) }); Because it's async you have to wait for the request to complete before trying to use it

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the how you type the code. $.get("/send").then(data), where is data from?

Comment: No problem, I didn't really explain to well. Basically, the line console.log(getData.responseJSON.result) is being executed before the .get() finishes and getData actually has data.

However, .get() does return an object that behaves like a js Promise. Promises have a member .then that accepts a function that handles what to do with the result of the method that returns the promise, in this case the response from /send.

Did you give it a shot? What did the console log out?

Comment: Basics of using Promises https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

I'll add an example so the code is easier to see

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I noticed if I set the function as a var c= $.get("/send").then(function(data){return data;}); it won't send the array,  but I can grab the data, and loop the array into the ul to generate a list. Thanks again. Really helped!

Comment: Awesome Michael, glad to help! I'm not super familiar with using jquery for ajax, so it doesn't make complete sense why that works without actually looking into it more. Anywho, happy to help!